# I will use ML Kit, what i want to know is that ML Kit supports Face Detection when recording?

Tags: ios, face-detection, google-mlkit

I will use ML Kit with swift.  ML Kit supports Face Detection when recording?

After extending "AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate", "AVCaptureMovieFileOutput"'s instance get "nil".

I need to be able to have AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput working at the same time.

Can I do that with "captureSession.addOutput"?

Is there any code to add when recoding with face detection?

Comment: Considering you are talking about video recording I could say no. But if you want to detect faces instead of face recognition  It could be better idea using Vision. In vision kit you could find faces much easier.

Comment: ML Kit supports face detection as long as you can feed it with a CMSampleBufferRef.  See an example in the quickstart sample app:  https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample/CameraViewController.swift#L186